# select count(*) from SimpleDB iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I want to return the count of items in this domain. I know count (*) returns one item called Domain with an attribute called Count. How do I get Count's value?

```
@try {
    SimpleDBSelectRequest  *selectRequest2  = [[SimpleDBSelectRequest alloc] initWithSelectExpression:@"select count(*) from %@"];
    SimpleDBSelectResponse *selectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager sdb] select:selectRequest2];

    for (SimpleDBItem *item in selectResponse.items) {
    if ( [item.name isEqualToString:@"Domain"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Attributes = %@",[item.attributes objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
    }
}
@catch (AmazonServiceException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception = %@", exception);
}
```

I get this for Attributes:

```
Attributes = {Name: Count,AlternateNameEncoding: (null),Value: 3,AlternateValueEncoding: (null),<SimpleDBAttribute: 0x8667120>}
```

How do I get the Value 3 out of it?

Comment: Does the code in the answer not work?  It should go just after, or in place of the `NSLog(@"Attributes...")` statement

Comment: This worked:for (SimpleDBAttribute *attr in item.attributes)
                {
                    if ([attr.name isEqualToString:@"Count"]) {
                        int total = [attr.value intValue];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
for (SimpleDBAttribute *attr in item.attributes) { if ([attr.name isEqualToString:@"Count"]) { int total = [attr.value intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `selectResponse` should have an `items` property which is a mutable array of `SimpleDBReplaceableAttribute` instances.  There should be one whose `name` property is "Count" and whose `value` property is a string representation of the count.

It would be something like:

```
    SimpleDBReplaceableAttribute *attribute = [[selectResponse items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger count = [[attribute value] integerValue];
```